# Pasar datos a modal desde un controller para usar razor y armar una tabla

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, razor

Tengo un llamada en mi javascript a un metodo de mi controller que hace lo siguiente

```
function Detalle() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Plan/Detalle',
        data: {
            id,
            periodo,
            trimestre
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#DetalleModal').modal('show');
        }
    })
}
```

En mi controller lo que hago es traerme los datos del servicio pegandole a la base de datos, para luego pasarlo al modal y usar razor para armar la tabla con los datos.

El problema que tengo es que no se como mandarlo al modal directo y usarlo sin pasar por el javascript.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Detalle(int id, int periodo, int trimestre)
        {
            var comp = _procesoCompService.Detalle(id, periodo, trimestre).Result;

            return Json(comp, jsonSettings);
        }
```

Lo que yo necesito es abrir el modal y pasarle los datos de **comp** para armar la tabla dentro del modal usando razor.

Yo recibo los datos en **comp** pero no se si deberia llamar al modal dentro del controller o como pasarle los datos.

Deberia tener una vista aparte del modal y llamarlo y ahi pasarle los datos de **comp**?

Porque una vez que vuelve los datos del comp al js lo que hago es abrir el modal desde el javascript, pero no se como pasarle los datos y armar la tabla desde el **.cshtml** y no usar el javascript para pasarle los tags

Tendria que cambie el Task por un ActionResult?

El modal es este

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="DetalleModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalDetalle">
                <table id="Detalle" class="table table-striped dataTable no-footer" role="grid" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead class="bg-info">
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col">Fecha solicitud</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nro Comp</th>
                            <th scope="col">Coordinador</th>
                            <th scope="col">Monto</th>
                            <th scope="col">Motivo Sol</th>
                            <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                            <th scope="col">MPA</th>
                            <th scope="col">MBA</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mot Est</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (Detalles dc in Model.Detalles)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>@dc.FechaSol</td>
                                <td>@dc.CodComp</td>
                                <td>@dc.Nombre @dc.Apellido</td>
                                <td>@dc.Monto</td>
                                <td>@dc.MotSol</td>
                                <td>@dc.DescEstado</td>
                                <td>@dc.MPA</td>
                                <td>@dc.MBA</td>
                                <td>@dc.MotEst</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero recibir en el modal el modelo de datos que me llega desde el backend y hacer un foreach con los datos

Comment: puedes explicar como estas armando el modal, es que yo conozco 2 formas, una es el modal dibujarlo con todo el html dando un result de un action, y la otra es cargarlo desde que cargas la vista con datos del modal

Comment: Si, ahi edite la pregunta y puse como esta armado el modal

Comment: Lo puse en un index.cshtml, tendria que separarlo y llamarlo en el index con un Html.Partial()? O hay una forma de pasarlo a la vista al modelo.

Comment: Pense que haciendo en el controller return PartialView("_Detalle", detalle); le podia pasar el el modelo que me traia (detalle) directo al modal pero no me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Mira primero que nada queria ver tu index para ver como estabas mandando llamar tu modal, pero bueno mi recomendación es la siguiente:

En tu index crea tu `<div id="myModal"> </div>` el cual ira vacío.
Luego en tu controlador

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Detalle(int id, int periodo, int trimestre)
        {
            var comp = _procesoCompService.Detalle(id, periodo, trimestre).Result;

            return PartialView("Direccion de mi modal/modal.htmlcs", comp);
        }
```

De esta forma estas retornando la vista parcial de tu modal, ahora para recivirlo en tu vista haces lo siguiente

```
function Detalle() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Plan/Detalle',
        data: {
            id,
            periodo,
            trimestre
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myModal').html('');
            $('#myModal').html(data);
            $('#DetalleModal').modal('show');
        }
    })
}
```

y con eso puedes estar cambiando la informacion del modal segun lo que estas consultando. Saludos